# How to do equation in Slider Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Im trying to change the maximum of a slider based on a Chooser. Something like

```
if confidence = "None" [set Maximum 1]
```

This is on the part of the slider that indicates the Maximum. However, i get the Expected Reporter Error, but i dont know how to do this right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution, in my opinion, is writing a reporter in your code tab and using that reporter to determine the maximum of your slider:

```
to-report slidermaximum
  
  if confidence = "none" [report 1]

end
```

[image]

Another option is using `ifelse-value`, which allows you to return a reporter rather than a command. This one you can put directly into the slider menu.

```
ifelse-value confidence = "none" [1] [10]
```

I prefer the first one, since code hidden within your different submenus is easy to forget or overlook when you are making changes to the model later on.

Comment: Thanks, the first one is indeed the best solution. Works like a charm now.